# SQL запрос со статическими атрибутами

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Есть две таблицы: "Работники" и "Услуги", и, допустим, таблица "Отчет"

таблица "Работники" представляет из себя таблицу где храняться данные о работниках какого-либо предприятия

таблица "Услуги" хранит информацию о услугах которые компания предоставляет

таблица "Отчет" соединяет услугу и выполнителя

```
Workers
ID uniqueidentifier,
Name varchar(max)


Services
ID uniqueidentifier
Name varchar(max)


Report
ServicesID -> Services
WorkerID -> Workers
Percent -> Процент выполненной работы
```

В таблице Report есть такие данные

```
SELECT S.Name Service, W.Name Worker, R.Percent
FROM
 Report AS R
LEFT JOIN Services AS S ON S.ID = R.ServicesID
LEFT JOIN Worker AS W ON W.ID = R.WorkerID
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно реализовать выборку которая отобразит 5 статических столбцов и заполнит их работниками которые выполняли услугу и какой процент этой работы они сделали. Вот такая выборка должна получиться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи, каким способом можна реализовать такой запрос? Пользуюсь SQL Server 2014

Comment: `PIVOT`. https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Akina, У меня же нет статических 5 работников, их может быть сотни, а там надо ставить IN и указывать значения

Comment: Тогда только динамический код. Или получите неиспоганенную выборку на клиента, и там выполните перекрёстный запрос локальными средствами.

Comment: вы работников пронумеруйте и будет у вас 5 статических номеров. тем более что потенциально работников может быть более 5, и в таком случаем вообще не понятно что делать из вашей задачи. можно предположить, что выводить следует первые 5 по %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что-то оказалось, что я никогда не писали пивоты на пару столбцов (:

исходные данные

```
declare @t table (services varchar(20), worker varchar(20), prcnt int);

insert into @t values 
('услуга 1','работник 1', 25),
('услуга 1','работник 2', 49),
('услуга 1','работник 3', 25),
('услуга 3','работник 1', 50),
('услуга 2','работник 12',100),
('услуга 1','работник 4', 35),
('услуга 3','работник 5', 50);
```

далее выборка данных в CTE с нумерацией работников по услугам в порядке убывания процента, и по имени.

```
;WITH rdata AS (
    select services
          ,worker
          ,prcnt
          , 'w' + cast(row_number() over (partition by services order by prcnt desc, worker asc) as varchar) as wnum          
          , 'p' + cast(row_number() over (partition by services order by prcnt desc, worker asc) as varchar) as pnum
    from @t
)

SELECT services
    ,max(p1) as p1
    ,max(w1) as w1
    ,max(p2) as p2
    ,max(w2) as w2
    ,max(p3) as p3
    ,max(w3) as w3
    ,max(p4) as p4
    ,max(w4) as w4
    ,max(p5) as p5
    ,max(w5) as w5  
FROM  rdata
PIVOT (
    max(worker) for wnum in ([w1],[w2],[w3],[w4],[w5])
) as pt1
PIVOT (
    MAX(prcnt) for pnum in ([p1], [p2], [p3], [p4], [p5])
) as pt2

GROUP BY services
ORDER BY services
```

и результат

```
services    p1     w1            p2      w2            p3       w3           p4     w4            p5      w5
----------- ------ ------------- ------- ------------- -------- ------------ ------ ------------- ------- -------
услуга 1    49     работник 2    35      работник 4    25       работник 1   25     работник 3    NULL    NULL
услуга 2    100    работник 12   NULL    NULL          NULL     NULL         NULL   NULL          NULL    NULL
услуга 3    50     работник 1    50      работник 5    NULL     NULL         NULL   NULL          NULL    NULL
```